# Spring (no Spring Boot) en netbeans

Tags: spring, netbeans-8.2

¿Cómo incluir el framework Spring (no Spring Boot) en netbeans?

Saludos.

---

Construí una aplicación maven desde el IDE netbeans. Este es mi pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <org.springframework.version>5.2.8.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>
    
    
     <repositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->
                  
     <repository>
        <id>repository.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Framework Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone/</url>
    </repository>
    
    
     <repository>
        <id>repository.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
        <name>Spring Framework Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/</url>
    </repository>
        
        
        
    </repositories>
    
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
          <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

          
    </dependencies>
    
</project>
```

Sin embargo, cuando intento probar un ejemplo en Spring obtengo el siguiente error: "error: package org.springframework.stereotype does not exist", al intentar esto:
"import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;" Al parecer no está reconociendo el framework Spring.

De forma similar se generan los siguintes errores:

```
COMPILATION ERROR : 
-------------------------------------------------------------
soundsystem/CDPlayerConfig.java:[8,45] error: package org.springframework.context.annotation does not exist
soundsystem/CDPlayerConfig.java:[9,45] error: package org.springframework.context.annotation does not exist
soundsystem/CDPlayerConfig.java:[12,1] error: cannot find symbol
soundsystem/CDPlayerConfig.java:[13,1] error: cannot find symbol
soundsystem/SgtPeppers.java:[7,37] error: package org.springframework.stereotype does not exist
soundsystem/SgtPeppers.java:[10,1] error: cannot find symbol
soundsystem/CDPlayerTest.java:[8,23] error: package org.junit does not exist
soundsystem/CDPlayerTest.java:[9,16] error: package org.junit does not exist
soundsystem/CDPlayerTest.java:[10,23] error: package org.junit.runner does not exist
soundsystem/CDPlayerTest.java:[12,39] error: package org.springframework.test.context does not exist
soundsystem/CDPlayerTest.java:[13,46] error: package org.springframework.test.context.junit4 does not exist
soundsystem/CDPlayerTest.java:[15,1] error: cannot find symbol
soundsystem/CDPlayerTest.java:[16,1] error: cannot find symbol
```

No reconoce casi ninguno de los elementos de Srping. El único que reconoce es este:

```
"import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;"
```

¿Me falta incluir alguna dependencia?

Comment: Netbeans es un IDE. Spring es un framework que usas en tus aplicaciones. Si no vas a usar Spring Boot tienes que crear una aplicación (web?) y añadir "manualmente" la inicialización de Spring en ella. Algo como esto: https://allaboutspringframework.com/java-spring-di-without-spring-boot/

Comment: Pablo Lozano:  Incluí el "spring-context" y mucho más. Pero igual me sigue dando error con elementos básicos de Spring.

Comment: podría ser que no esta viendo un servidor para desplegar spring.

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar tu pom.xml actualizado? Porque mencionas que haz estado agregando dependencias, pero si sigues teniendo el error original, te hace falta por ejemplo junit, que si fuera la versión 4.12 tendrías que agregar algo como:

    <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>4.12</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>